# How to use 'continue' with requests-futures?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, request, continue, requests-futures

I have a code where I want to fetch results from the web. And I want my code to wait if the internet connection goes down. But when I tried to perform a continue statement within the for loop it's giving me some tricky results. And I don't know how to solve it.

**Code:**

```
import requests
import time
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession

def wait_for_con():
    con = False
    while not con:
        try:
            response = requests.get("https://google.com")
            if response.status_code == 200:
                con = True
        except ConnectionError:
            time.sleep(1)



def run (targets):
    with FuturesSession() as session:
        futures = [session.get(target) for target in targets]
        for future in futures:
            try:
                result = future.result()
                status = result.status_code
                print (str(status)+"    "+result.url)
                
            except ConnectionError:
                print ("waitng for connection")
                wait_for_con()
                continue
run(my_url_list)
```

While i tried to run it offline and go online,
It's printing " waiting for connection" again and again.

**Output:**

```
waiting for connection
waiting for connection
waiting for connection
waiting for connection
waiting for connection
waiting for connection
waiting for connection
waiting for connection
waiting for connection

Printing Continues...
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where does `get` come from in line `response = get("https://google.com")`?

Comment: Be aware HTTP is a connection-less protocol

Comment: @Pynchia sorry I forget to use "from requests import get" instead of "import requests".

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is simple that if connection is missing then even in the beginning itself you won't be able to get success
Use This code:

```
import requests
import time
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession


def wait_for_con():
    con = False
    while not con:
        try:
            response = requests.get("https://google.com")
            if response.status_code == 200:
                con = True
                print("connect")
        except ConnectionError:
            print("trying")
            time.sleep(1)


def run(targets):
    with FuturesSession() as session:
        futures = [session.get(target) for target in targets]
        n = len(futures)
        while (n):

            try:
                n -= 1
                result = futures[n].result()
                status = result.status_code
                print(str(status) + "    " + result.url)

            except ConnectionError:
                print("waitng for connection")
                wait_for_con()
                time.sleep(1)
                print("connection stable")
                futures = [session.get(target) for target in targets]

                # result = future.result()
                # status = result.status_code
                # print(str(status)+"    "+result.url)


my_url_list = ['https://pypi.org/project/requests-futures/',
               'https://pypi.org/project/requests-futures/',
               'https://pypi.org/project/requests-futures/',
               ]
run(my_url_list)
```